# SQL dense_rank counter within time period

Tags: sql, sql-server, counter, dense-rank

I would like to add a counter to records in my table, that fall in the last rolling 12 months.

Below is what I've tried and what I would like to achieve. The current counter doesn't reset to 1 for a different customer ID.

```sql
select *,
case when order_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) then dense_rank() over (partition by customer_id order by case when order_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) then order_date end asc, order_no)
              end as counter
from mydata
```

| customer_id | order_no | order_date | counter | what I want |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1213 | Wednesday, May 12, 2021 | 1 | 1 |
| ABC | 1257 | Saturday, May 15, 2021 | 2 | 2 |
| ABC | 1345 | Saturday, May 22, 2021 | 3 | 3 |
| ABC | 4562 | Saturday, May 22, 2021 | 4 | 4 |
| ABC | 4362 | Saturday, May 29, 2021 | 5 | 5 |
| ABC | 1421 | Tuesday, June 1, 2021 | 6 | 6 |
| GHI | 5525 | Wednesday, January 20, 2021 | NULL | NULL |
| GHI | 2452 | Friday, February 26, 2021 | NULL | NULL |
| GHI | 1452 | Tuesday, March 2, 2021 | 3 | 1 |
| GHI | 3525 | Wednesday, March 3, 2021 | 4 | 2 |
| GHI | 4242 | Thursday, March 4, 2021 | 5 | 3 |
| GHI | 1341 | Thursday, March 4, 2021 | 6 | 4 |
| GHI | 1341 | Thursday, March 4, 2021 | 6 | 4 |
| GHI | 5241 | Saturday, March 13, 2021 | 7 | 5 |
| GHI | 1425 | Saturday, March 20, 2021 | 8 | 6 |
| GHI | 5213 | Wednesday, March 31, 2021 | 9 | 7 |
| GHI | 6312 | Saturday, April 17, 2021 | 10 | 8 |
| GHI | 6312 | Saturday, April 17, 2021 | 10 | 8 |

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restart at a given point, you need to partition at that point. So not only by customer_id but also your condition:

```
SELECT mydata.*
     , CASE
         WHEN calc.in_scope = 1
         THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY mydata.customer_id, calc.in_scope 
                                     ORDER BY order_date, order_no)
       END AS counter
  FROM mydata
 CROSS
 APPLY (SELECT IIF(order_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()), 1, 0) AS in_scope
     ) calc
```

I've moved the calculation into `CROSS APPLY` to avoid repeating it, in case it needs to change in the future you'd then only change it in one place.

[Working demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8b709a3fb171cbb96ee862ae70cac1fc)

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is easy to understand and I am grateful that you shared a working demo.